# Sleuth 2 with spring boot 2 not adding traceid in logs

Tags: logging

I have recently started exploring sping boot 2. I am uisng logaback for logging purpose. For distributed logging tracing, I wanted to use sping boot sleuth starter. But with below dependency in pom.xml without zipkin integration its not adding traceid in logs.Also added spring.application.name property in application.properties file. Am I missing anything here?

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
       <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

What logging framework are you using? I was using log4j2 in my project. It started working when I removed log4j2 and left it to the default logging of spring-cloud-sleuth.

Comment: SLF4J is the main logging system, where as Log4J is a logger implementation. It's actually recommended you not use the default loggers and instead use something like Log4J, or some other implementation